# Creating a sitemap using PrestaSitemap Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sitemap

I have installed the PrestaSitemap bundle following the official [documentation](https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaSitemapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-Installation.md).

I'm trying to implement an `Eventlistener` as described in [chapter 5](https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaSitemapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-Usage-Event_Listener.md).

I have a list of "blog articles" that need to be included and as such I know I will need to add a Listener.  To make this example simple I want to just get the homepage URL added to the sitemap (I can get the blog articles later).  This is what my code looks like so far:

```
public function populateSitemap(SitemapPopulateEvent $event)
{
    $section = $event->getSection();
    if (is_null($event->getSection()) || $event->getSection() == 'mysection') {
        $event->getGenerator()->addUrl(
            new UrlConcrete(
                $url,
                new \DateTime(),
                UrlConcrete::CHANGEFREQ_HOURLY,
                1
            ),
            'mysection'
        );
    }
}
```

However when I run the command

> bin/console presta:sitemaps:dump

The sitemap does *not* have the correct settings as it shows the change frequency as daily instead of hourly.  I don't think this code is running at all.  Sadly their "[working example](http://sandbox.prestacms.com/)" is not working at all.

The Homepage Controller looks like this:

```
class HomepageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_homepage", options={"sitemap" = true})
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('homepage/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

The routing looks like this: (config/routing.yml)

```
wbpractices:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
PrestaSitemapBundle:
    resource: "@PrestaSitemapBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Comment: Did you clear your application- and opcode-cache (php7 has opcache for cli, too) after latest changes before you tried to dump the sitemap?

Comment: I'm not using any cache (brand new app I've just started building) yet and this is also my dev environment. (I've just added the controller to the question... just in case something is wrong with it)

Comment: well ... you're using symfony ... and php - there's almost always some caching involved. symfony by default uses routing-, classmap-, translation-, annotation-, template-, doctrine-proxy -cache, ... did you run `app/console cache:clear --env=dev` before you tried to dump the sitemap? That was my question basically.

Comment: "There's almost always some caching" true.

Anyway I've just run that command now, but sadly no luck

Comment: Could you add your service/routing configuration?

Comment: I've added the routing conf to the original question

Comment: so, did you solve this issue?

Comment: @DenisAlimov, yes I did. You can see my example code here: https://github.com/JRCrawford/wbpractices